# Anyone know what is wrong with my JSON text? - Expecting 'EOF', '}', ':', ',', ']',

Tags: json

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here? Cant seem to get this to be validated on [www.jsonlint.com](http://www.jsonlint.com)?
I appreciate any help on what I am doing incorrectly! Thanks!

### Error: Parse error on line 17:
...,            "text": "{"         structuredContent ":

Expecting 'EOF', '}', ':', ',', ']', got 'undefined'

```
{
    "output": {
        "intents": [{
            "intent": "FantasyFootball",
            "confidence": 0.28373377919197085
        }],
        "entities": [],
        "generic": [{
            "response_type": "text",
            "text": "Your account has been created."
        }, {
            "time": 2000,
            "typing": true,
            "response_type": "pause"
        }, {
            "response_type": "text",
            "text": "{"  <----Error structuredContent ":  Expecting 'EOF', '}', ':', ',', ']', got 'undefined'
            structuredContent ":{"
            message ":"
            How would you like to receive a password reset ? ","
            quickReplies ":{"
            type ":"
            quickReplies ","
            replies ":[{"
            type ":"
            button ","
            click ":{"
            actions ":[{"
            text ":"
            Mobile ","
            type ":"
            publishText "}]},"
            title ":"
            Mobile "},{"
            type ":"
            button ","
            click ":{"
            actions ":[{"
            text ":"
            Email ","
            type ":"
            publishText "}]},"
            title ":"
            Email "}],"
            itemsPerRow ":2}}}"
        }]
    },
    "user_id": "662234bd-7e10-458f-8bed-58d251020b17"
}
```

Comment: You’re missing a comma. Actually all the JSON after “text” looks quite broken. May you indent it and show what you think it should be?

Answer (score 0):

"text" is a key, and the value is "{" which is fine, but then you need a , followed by the the next key/value pair.  The next entry is not using the right format for a object entry ("key": "value"):

```
            "text": "{"
            structuredContent ":{"
            message ":"
```

Answer (score 0):

The JSON is completely broken after that point. As it says, the next character after `"{"` needs to be one of those listed (most likely you want a comma). But the next lines are missing colons and commas, too.